# Is it possible to wire 2 short led strips with 6 pin (ON-OFF-ON) SPDT switch

Tags: switches, power-electronics, wiring, led-strip

Need help. Is it possible to wire 2 short led strips with 6 pin (ON-OFF-ON) SPDT switch in that way to have:

A) One led strip - ON, second - OFF;

B) Both strips  - ON;

Components: 6-PIN SPDT switch, 1 power supply, 2 led strips

Comment: Are you allowed to use more components???  Add a diode, I think it can be done.  Or use a DPDT switch, much easier.

Comment: Are you sure you have a spdt switch? If it has 6 pins, it may well be a dpdt switch.

Comment: Sorry, it is dpdt.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is DPDT switch and its schema is a much easier

[image]

Comment: Hi, It seems that you have [answered your own question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) - good! So please remember to come back and accept your answer (or another answer, if a better one has been added) in a couple of days time i.e. no sooner than 48 hours after you asked the question. That will close the topic and remove the question from the unanswered list. Thanks.